# Exporting form data to google spreadsheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a registration form in my rails app, I want to be able to export the contents o the form to google spreadsheet. I am using the google_drive gem. How do I achieve this? The only resource I have about this seem to be outdated and no google search has been productive.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a gem for exporting your *ActiveRecord*/*Mongoid* model records to *Google Sheets*: [model_to_googlesheet](https://github.com/lakesare/model_to_googlesheet).

Then you can export your record with something along the lines with:

```
User.last.export_to_googlesheet spreadsheet: 'Hi', googlesheet: 'Wow'`
```

and a collection of records with

```
User.export_to_googlesheet
```

It can be configured to update records if they exist in the spreadsheet, to delete records from spreadsheet on deletion, to customize exported hash, etc.